# Insert row when cell above and below are different

Tags: excel, vba

How would you insert a row if, in the specified column the row above and below are different. For example:
`A1 : Hello

A2 : Hello

A3 : Goodbye`

You would want to insert a row under row 2 and move 3 down.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that the value two rows above is different? What code do you have so far?

Comment: the column is sorted alphabetically, so when there is a difference, I would like to place a space between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub insert()
    dim lastrow as long, i as long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Not Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            Rows(i).insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you set as 'lastrow'?

Comment: lastrow does not need to be set as anything, it gets set to the last row in column A

Comment: You are welcome, the edit only declared the variables which should only be an issue if you have option explicit on.